# passing attributes of superclass to subclass

Tags: java

I have Employee, manager class.

employee has private String name, int age, double salary. they have to be placed in one method. i placed them in String details

```
public void details(String name,int age, double salary)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.salary=salary;
  }
```

then they have to be passed down to class manager but theres a new attribute to be added, which is department.

```
class Manager extends Employee{
    private string department;
}
```

thats my problem, i cant output the attributes together with the attribute department.

---

**UPDATE #1**

I've tried using this code before:

```
public void details(String name, int age, double salary, String dept) 
{
   super(name, age, salary);
   this.dept = dept;
}
```

But it gives me error that the call to super must be first statement in constructor.

this is how my manager extends employee class looks like.

```
class Manager extends Employee 
{
    private String department;
    public Manager(String name,int age,double salary,String department)
    {
        super(name,age,salary);
        this.department=department;
     }

     public String getDetails()
     {
         return super.details;
     }

     public void details(String name, int age, double salary, String department) 
     {
         super(name, age, salary);
         this.department = department;
     }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

The attributes name, age and salary has to be private. I've tried changing it to public and use `super.details(name age salary)` and it worked. I've tried the same codes but with private attribute but it didn't work .

Comment: You've listed 3 different languages.  Please pick one!

Answer (score 2):

Private means private, as in, no other class can access them. Your two options are: make getter/setter methods in the parent class or make the variables protected so "Manager" can see them. I'd give my opinion on which is better, but you haven't told us the "why" piece of your question...

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the values your subclass inherits as properties.

```
class Employee
{
    private String name;

    //constructor
    public Employee(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
         this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are trying to call `details(String name, int age, double salary)` from `details(String name, int age, double salary, String dept)` using the keyword `super`. These methods have different signature. So, you cannot call `super` in the subclass method details.

The signature of a method (with exception of the constructors) are composed of three elements. The method's visibility, name, value that returns and parameters.

In this case, The Manager method `public void details(String name, int age, double salary, String department)` is public, returns void, its name is details and has four parameters a String, int, double and String again, but the Employee method `public void details(String name, int age, double salary, String department)` is different in the parameters. This method has only three parameters a String, int and double.

In this situation you can call details directly or override the method (the second solution can not assign `department` to the details. So, I recommend you the direct call).

```
class Employee
{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double salary;

    public Employee (String name, int age, double salary, String department)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public void details(String name, int age, double salary)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
         this.name = name;
    }
    ...
}

class Manager extends Employee 
{
    private String department;

    public Manager(String name, int age, double salary, String department)
    {
        // Here is correct to call super() because the constructors have the same signature.
        // This is, the method visibility and name. The parameters are optional.
        super(name, age, salary);
        this.department = department;
    }

    // Direct call.
    public void details(String name, int age, double salary, String department) 
    {
        // Here you CANNOT use super because in Employee there no method with the same signature.
        // So, just call the method details(name, age, salary) that is public.
        details(name, age, salary);
        this.department = department;
    }

    // Overriding the method
    @Override
    public void details(String name,int age, double salary)
    {
        // Here is correct to call super() because you are overriding the super class method.
        // The problem is that this method doesn't have the parameter deparment.
        super(name, age, salary);
        // Do something else
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably the best way to handle this is for the Manager class to override the details() method, adding the new parameter:

Manager class

```
public void details(String name, int age, double salary, String dept) {
   super.details(name, age, salary);
   this.dept = dept;
}
```

Comment: `super()` tries to call the constructor. Did you mean `super.details(name, age, salary)` ?

Comment: The point is that the Manager.details() method has the additional parameter, but leverages the superclass' details() method with its parameters unchanged.

Comment: Yes, but phihag's point is that this code doesn't compile as is. :)